# Yii2, Facebook and Twig

Tags: facebook, authentication, twig, yii2

I'm trying to build a rather simple site, and my biggest hurdle is getting facebook login working.
I'm trying to use the authclient extension to log in with facebook. I've set everything up according to docs.. but I don't know how to initiate the process of logging in.

I've built a fb connect based on the sdk before and I'd really rather not...
Now my next question, how do I access template functions in twig and plugins through a twig template?

Such as this:

```
        <?= yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
            'baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth']
        ]); ?>
```

I've used cakephp before on a pretty big project, but I'm completely new to yii.

Comment: Dropped twig since it's only holding me back at this point. Would still like to use twig though, so the question stays.

Answer (score 0):

The twig integration isn't really the smoothest yet. You can register a namespace, and then there should be a *_begin and *_end function for twig, i.e.

```
{{ use('philippfrenzel/yii2masonry/Yii2masonry') }}


{{ yii2masonry_begin({
    'clientOptions': {
        'columnWidth' : 50,
        'itemSelector' : '.item',
    }
}) }}
```

Important is to note the json style of options, and the capitalization of the namespace and twig function.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Actually in the case of the default facebook stuff, it both did not work and was not needed.